# I cannot create an array on a text object, only along Y

Tags: modifiers

I have created a text object, and would like to make an array of it along the Y axis.
Arrays on X and Z work fine, but I cannot seem to make an array on Y.

[image]

I can't understand why this wouldn't work? I've tried to change some of the settings in Array, but no success...

[image]

Comment: I guess along Y works... but your object is flat, so 'relative offset' will create duplicates at the same place. To do that, use 'constant offset' instead. Note that your object is rotated, so along Y (global) is Z (local) for the object.

Comment: Oh yes! That fixed it. Thanks! For some reason I thought the value "1" implied some distance (like creating an array along the Z moves it up a certain distance), or that the planes were never "0" depth. Thank you! Solved it.

Comment: Relative offset is relative to the object's size. 0.9 = 90% of the size, 1 = the size, 2 = 2x the size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object which has no thickness can be duplicated by an array modifier using relative offset but the duplicated objects are at the same place as the original, as relative offset's values are relative to the object's dimensions.

It appears as if nothing was happening.

If you want to see these duplicates in this case, use 'constant offset' instead:

[image]